# check box check all not working after search using xmlhttprequest

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with my code. The checkbox check/uncheck all works on first load as all employee list are displayed. But when I select the dropdown for a specific group of employees, it displays the selected group of employees but the check box check/uncheck all doesn't work anymore. I am using xmlhttprequest on searching a group of employees. Please help. I have been a stackoverflow searcher on all my codes but even searching all over the internet I couldn't find the right answer.

Here's a sample of my code on dropdown onchange:

```
function searchStatus(str) {
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
$("#dvloader").show();
if (str.length==0) {
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
//document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
$("#dvloader").hide();
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  $("#dvloader").hide();
  //document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";

    /// can add another function here
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","findStatus.php?employee="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

A sample code or program would be very helpful. Thank you very much in advance.

Here's what the div "livesearch" looks like to give you an overview of what's really happening:

```
<div id="livesearch" class="span12">

<?php
// SQL query
//$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE '$status' = '$status' ORDER BY emp_lname 
ASC";

//$employee = ucwords($employee);

            $strSQL =  "SELECT * ";
            $strSQL .= "FROM employees ";
            $strSQL .= "ORDER BY emp_lname ASC ";

            //In MySQL syntax ucase function is the same with the PHP's
            //ucase function

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
            $num = 0;

            $rec_count = mysql_num_rows($rs);
            ?>
            <?php
            if($rec_count < 1){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button"></button>
            <strong>Information: </strong>No results. Search again.
            </div>
            <?php
            } else {

            }

            ?>

<form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="selection">
<table align="center" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input class="checkall" type="checkbox" value="" onclick="check();"/></th>
<th>Employee Number</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Middle Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php


            // Loop the recordset $rs
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $num++;
            ?>
<tr>
<td><input class="checkbox1" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" 
value="<?php echo $row['emp_num'];?>"/></td>
<td><?php echo $row['emp_num'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_fname'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_mname'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_lname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['emp_status'];?></td>
<td><a href="basic.php?emp_num=<?php echo $row["emp_num"];?>">View Records</a></td>
                        </tr>
            <?php
            }
//<td><a href='basic.php?emp_num={$row["emp_num"]}'>View Records</a></td>
//<td><a href='basic.php?delete_emp={$row["emp_num"]}'>Delete Employee</a></td>
            ?>
</tbody>
</table>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` instead of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: can you share the code that does check/uncheck all functionality... sounds like you are not using event delegation to dynamic elements

Comment: whether the check all is inside the `livesearch`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny

Here's my check/uncheck all:

`$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
 
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny 

no, it's in javascript..i named it check.js..sorry for a very noob question..newbie here.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are dealing with dynamic elements and is not using event delegation to handle that case.

So use event delegation syntax of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle dynamic elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkall', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Since you are already using jQuery there is no need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to do the ajax request and worry about the browser comparability issues... use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or in this case the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method like

```
function searchStatus(str) {
    var $live = $("#livesearch").empty();
    if (str.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    $("#dvloader").show();
    $live.load("findStatus.php?employee=" + str, function () {
        $("#dvloader").hide();
    })
}
```

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: still not working..actually..i do my search on basic.php..when the user searches using dropdown, findstatus.php gets the value of the dropdown and displays a new set of employee list based on the dropdown value.

Comment: can you add more samples? I'm really not good at this but I know I am asking the right people here who has great talents in programming.

Comment: @user3746866 can you try `$(document).on('click', '.checkall', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});`

Comment: also tried your code just now..still not working..it only works on first load with all the employees list..but doesn't work after ajax refresh on user selection with selected group.. :(

Comment: @user3746866 after the ajax request is there an element with class `checkall`

Comment: yes..there is..inside the `findStatus.php` the check/uncheck all button is `class="checkall"` the check/uncheck all inside `basic.php` also has `class="checkall"`

Comment: sorry for the late reply..i was busy adding codes to my question..you can see some changes and an overview inside `<div id="livesearch" >`

Comment: i think i just solved my own problem..but your code really helped me think harder..and even made my code shorter..very much thanks.. :)

Comment: @user3746866 what was the problem

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.checkall', function () { $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked); });` - this code works brilliantly but at first it wasn't working because the `class="checkall"` was not found in the `findStatus.php` on the check/uncheck all checkbox..THANK YOU VERY MUCH..you really greatly helped me on this.. :)